# How can i draw rectangle and bind data from Json in page.aspx?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, json, ajax, drawrectangle

I have a page.aspx. I don't know can i draw rectangle in page.
Example: data from JSON : `{name:Food;name:Candy;name:Water;name:Meat;......}`
and rectangle bind data with count of number data name. In here, I have 4 names data then 4 rectangle,

If i have 10 names data then 10 rectangle and I want draw them as follow 
[image]

If you know about this, share with me, please.(can use ajax jquery)
Thank you so much.

Comment: your json is invalid

Comment: Oh,assuming the data was there, and from  JSON string, main "draw rectangle and bind data"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
var obj = {name:['Food','Candy','Water','Meat']}
$.each(obj.name,function(i,v){
   $('ul').append('<li>'+v+'</li>');
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/zztougcb/

exp:

Comment: Hi @madalin ivascu , look so good, and i need a line , join them. Can you help me ?